# If com valores de array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, map

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
const usuarios = [
   {user: "teste", pass: "teste"},
   {user: "exemplo", pass: "example"},

]



function Login() {
    var done=0;
    var usuario = document.getElementsByName('usuario')[0].value;
    usuario=usuario.toLowerCase();
    var senha= document.getElementsByName('senha')[0].value;
    senha=senha.toLowerCase();
    
    if (usuario=="teste" && senha=="teste") {
      alert("Ok!");
      window.location.href = "/loginok.html";
      done=1;
    }
        
    if (done==0) { alert("Dados incorretos, tente novamente"); }
  }
```

Eu gostaria de que aqui, no lugar do  `if (usuario=="teste" && senha=="teste")"`, ele verificasse o usuário e a senha com os valores que estão no array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar o método find para selecionar o utilizador no array e depois verificas a password.

```
function Login() {
    var done=0;
    var usuario = document.getElementsByName('usuario')[0].value;
    usuario=usuario.toLowerCase();
    var senha= document.getElementsByName('senha')[0].value;
    senha=senha.toLowerCase();
    
    var usuario_obj = usuarios.find(u => {
        return u.user == usuario;
    })

    if (usuario_obj != undefined) {
        if (senha == usuario_obj.pass) {
            alert("Ok!");
            window.location.href = "/loginok.html";
            done=1;
        }
    }
        
    if (done==0) { alert("Dados incorretos, tente novamente"); }
}
```